# Problem in KnowRob

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I have a problem with try to launch both mod_vis.launch and communication_vis.launch
this is the error which I got,
process[communication_vis-2]: started with pid [9871]
find: `/jre/lib/': No such file or directory

Thanks in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46915/problem-in-knowrob/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting JAVA_HOME.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-28**:
My settings: echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java export JAVA_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export PATH' >> ~/.bashrc

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-28**:
please can you explain why this error appears, however I install  ros-fuerte-knowrob ?!

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-28**:
I don't know why. Set JAVA_HOME is part of my own ROS installation process. Maybe someone knows that...

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-28**:
I do not Know why java at all :(

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-10-28**:
The visualizations for KnowRob are written in Java, and some parts require JAVA_HOME to be set. For me, setting JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun works (assuming you have Sun Java 6 installed)

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-28**:
OK thanka I will try this

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-29**:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
cd /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib
cd /etc
sudo vi bash.bashrc
Then I add this and save
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java export JAVA_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOM

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-29**:
I do this instructions but when I run mod_vis it does not give an error but stop working at
%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_vis/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 24,464 bytes
% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_vis/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.40 sec, 1,546,852 bytes
so what ?!